# copying constructor and operator= (multiple arrays...)

Tags: c++, struct, char

i have to create a copy constructor and assignment operator= for Reg class.
But i have theese complicated structures and don't know how to copy it correctly.
So, Question is, how can i create copy constructor for class Reg - shallow copy?
Another question is, how should operator= look like - it should be a deep copy of Reg

```
    struct TMoves
        {
            const char* ddate;
            const char* sstreet;
            const char* ccity;

    public:

           ~TMoves()
          {
           delete [] ccity;
           delete [] ddate;
           delete [] sstreet;
          }

        };

    struct TData
    {
        int stackmult;
        const char* iid;
        const char* nname;
        const char* ssurname;
        int pocet;
        TMoves** moves;
        public:
        TData()
            {
                stackmult=1;
            }
        ~TData()
            {
                delete [] iid;
                delete [] nname;
                delete [] ssurname;

                for(int i=0;i<pocet;i++)
                {
                    delete moves[i];
                }

                delete [] moves;
            }

    };


class Reg
 {
   public:

        Reg ();
        Reg (const Regr&);
        ~Reg();
        Reg& operator= (const Reg &);

        bool Add (const char* id,   const char* name, const char* surname, const char* date, const char* street, const char* city );
        bool Resettle ( const char* id, const char* date, const char* street, const char* city );
   private:
        static const int MAX=1000; //default lenght of pole
        TData **pole;
        int counter; // pole lenght counter - not important now
        int multiplier; // used for realocating pole
 };

Reg::Reg()
{
    counter=0;
    multiplier=1;
    pole=new TData*[multiplier*MAX];

}
Reg::Reg(const Reg& out)
{

//... how?

}
Reg::Reg &operator= (const Reg& copy)
{

//... how?

}
```

in method Add - here i find correct place(misto) where should i place id - using binary search

```
int misto=counter;
pole[misto]=new TData;

char *temp = new char[12];
    strcpy(temp, id);
    pole[misto]->iid = temp;

temp = new char[strlen(name)+1];
    strcpy(temp, name);
    pole[misto]->nname = temp;

temp = new char[strlen(surname)+1];
    strcpy(temp, surname);
    pole[misto]->ssurname = temp;


pole[misto]->moves=new TMoves*[STAT];
pole[misto]->moves[0]=new TMoves;

temp = new char[strlen(city)+1];
    strcpy(temp,city);
    pole[misto]->moves[0]->ccity= temp;

temp = new char[strlen(date)+1];
    strcpy(temp,date);
    pole[misto]->moves[0]->ddate= temp;

temp = new char[strlen(street)+1];
    strcpy(temp,street);
    pole[misto]->moves[0]->sstreet= temp;
```

in method Ressetle - i find id - i have to find place where shall i add another info(city,street,date) and i create to it new TMoves:

```
pole[misto]->moves[misto2]=new TMoves;

char *temp = new char[strlen(city)+1];
strcpy(temp,city);
pole[misto]->moves[misto2]->ccity= temp;

temp = new char[strlen(date)+1];
strcpy(temp,date);
pole[misto]->moves[misto2]->ddate= temp;

temp = new char[strlen(street)+1];
strcpy(temp,street);
pole[misto]->moves[misto2]->sstreet= temp;
```

This topic may be confusing, but my code is soo long  and i am facing "only" to theese two problems with copying. Thank you for your time and replies.

Comment: Is this homework? Can you just avoid having so many pointers and using standard library types? (std::string, std::vector...)

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but your `TMoves` struct should have a constructor. You are calling `delete []` on the members, but if you don't construct them with default values of `nullptr`, than you could end up calling delete on junk data if you create a `TMove` object, but don't set each member.

Comment: yes, it is homework, i can't use vector and string.

Comment: Writing copy ctors etc. according to the Rule of Three is so C++98. In C++11, you should prefer the [Rule of Zero](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html), which says, in short, that you should wrap up ownership policies in separate classes (like std::unique_ptr, std::shared_ptr, etc.) and use those and RAII to manage your resources automagically. Much less error-prone and it's the idiomatic way to work.

Answer (score 2):

Don't give different kinds of semantics to copy constructor and copy assignment operator.

By default both should give a free-standing copy.

The best implementation of a copy constructor is to rely on copy construction of members and just use the compiler-generated one. To do this, use `std::string` instead of `char*`, and use `std::vector` for other arrays. It's that simple.

---

For the **homework** situation where you have been explicitly instructed to not use `string` and `vector`, define your own such classes.

Keep to the maxim that each class manages at most one resource, such as a dynamically allocated thingy.